# Create table name dynamically in JDBC programe

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am trying to prepare attendance sheet using excel and would like to save the file in .csv format further will linkup this with mysql.How can i create a table name dynamically through jdbc program.
Any help could be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this for table creation using JDBC http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-create-a-table/

Comment: I recommend to revise your planned data model. Dynamic table creation does not seem as a good practice to me unless there is a really good reason for this strategy.

Comment: @LRA- Totally agree with you. But if this is still needed, OP should not use application code to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to generate the SQL by "string bashing".  For example:

```
   String tableName = ...
   String createTableSQL = "Create table " + tableName;
   Statement statement = connection.createStatement(createTableSQL);
   statememt.execute();
```

and so on.

Warning: there are risks with this approach.  In particular, if you generate the table name based on a character string that the user enters or that you read from a spreadsheet or CSV or something, they could enter a string that is actually an SQL statement.  The net result is that they could trick your program into executing harmful SQL against your database.

The normal defence against this is to use a PreparedStatement, and use placeholders for all of the user-supplied details in the SQL.  Unfortunately, this only works for injecting SQL values.  You can't do this with a table name, a column name and various other things.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a `.sql+shell` script with `mysql command-line-client` and `mysql-dataloader`

The skeleton should go like this:

- Generate `.csv` file named`attendence_dd_mm_yyyy.csv` using your application.
- 'Shell Command': Create table_name on basis of some logic( e.g. `attendence_dd_mm_yyyy`).
- 'Mysql command': Use `mysql -u usename -ppassword -e <Create table tablename> <fixed columns>`.
- 'Data-loader': Use `mysql -u usename -ppassword -e LOAD DATA INFILE ...` to load csv to newly created table.

I know I am little off-topic still suggesting this option because

- Data-loader is very - very fast and readily available.
- It will solve you problem of data loading, which has to be done after table creation.
- You need not give `DDL permission` to your application code. Issues might occur if your code goes in `infinite loop` or something similiar.
- Issues will `propagate to DB` impact other connected applications(if any) as well.
- If yours is a Web-application or similiar, `SQL-Injection` is the `HUGE CONCERN` for your approach.

If you are using any other data-base, please work on similiar lines.